Can't compile Neovim with custom GCC path
I am on a CentOS 7.9 (end of life distribution) server with no admin rights, and the system GCC version (4.8) is incompatible with building Neovim.
So I installed GCC 14.2 and put it in my PATH as both gcc and gcc-14.2, as well as g++ and g++-14.2.
Then in the Neovim source directory, I compile like this:
make CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/custom/gcc-14.2 \
    CMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-14.2 CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-14.2 \
    DEPS_CMAKE_FLAGS="-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-14.2 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-14.2"

To explain that command, Neovim bundles some dependencies, and DEPS_CMAKE_FLAGS can be used to customize their compilation. In fact, these fail with older GCC but succeed when I give them the proper flags.
However, I have the feeling that GCC 4.8.5 was used to compile nvim itself, as per the output of:
strings -a ./build/bin/nvim | grep 'GCC: ('

GCC: (GNU) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)
GCC: (GNU) 14.2.0

How can I enforce the use of my local GCC ? (Do I have to edit the Makefile?)

Usually you just pass the CC variable to make or configure

I did export CC=gcc-14.2; export CXX=g++-14.2; before running the make command, but I still get the same strings output. There is no configure step for building Neovim.

Update: it seems that it indeed works, despite the unchanged strings output. I see it in the output of ./build/bin/nvim -V1 -v that has a line Compilation: ~/bin/gcc-14.2 [...].

Feel free to self-answer :)

I am going to post the same self answer that I made on the github issue thread:
I found out that the output of strings -a build/bin/nvim is not reflecting which compiler compiled the final executable.
When nvim is compiled with the flag CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo, then nvim -V1 -v shows a line for the compile command, indicating the wanted GCC was used:
Compilation: /path/to/custom/gcc-14.2 -O2 -g -Og -g -flto=auto [...]

And either one of the following calls successfully sets the custom GCC version:
make -j8 install \
    CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/custom/gcc-14.2 \
    CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo \
    CMAKE_EXTRA_FLAGS="-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-14.2" \
    DEPS_CMAKE_FLAGS="-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-14.2"

or simply:
make -j8 install \
    CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/custom/gcc-14.2 \
    CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo \
    CC=gcc-14.2 \
    DEPS_CMAKE_FLAGS="-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-14.2"

Not sure why the output of strings -a also shows my system GCC, but anyway I'll be fine I guess.
